# How to make VS Code recognize different include Paths in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, intellisense, ncurses

when I write `#include <ncurses.h>` IntelliSense gives me an Error saying:

```
#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit
cannot open source file "ncurses.h"
```

When I write `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` it works without any errors, but I would like it to work without the `ncurses/`.

The `ncurses.h` file is in the following path: `D:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses`.

What I've tried (without any success):

1. I already tried to modify the `tasks.json` by putting `-I/mingw64/include/ncurses` in there:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I/mingw64/include/ncurses",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

2. I also tried to modify `c_cpp_properties.json` by adding an includePath (I also tried forcedInclude):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

One thing to note: When I run my Makefile, it works without any errors (I had to add an include there):

```
CXX := c++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -std=c++20

# Contain path for any includes (headers)
# Depending on your platform: Include a path to boost, on linux should be 
# /usr/local/include, on mac could be /opt/homebrew/include
INCLUDES := -I/mingw64/include/ncurses -I./include

# Contains libraries we need to (-L is directory search path, -l is lib)
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib 
LDLIBS = -lncurses

SRCDIR := ./src
BREAKOUT_OBJECTS := controller_console.o model_simulator_breakout.o observer.o view_console.o main.o

breakout: $(BREAKOUT_OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
    
%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -DNCURSES_STATIC
clean:
    test ! -f breakout || rm breakout
    rm *.o
```

But I would like IntelliSense to also recognize `ncurses.h` so that I have auto completion and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what worked for me was removing the following line from `c_cpp_properties.json`:

`"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"`.

It seems that VS Code ignores includePaths when this is set

Comment: presumably when that line is set, configuration providence defers to that extension. so now the question is why your Makefile configuration wasn't working for that Makefile extension.